# bash: syntax error near unexpected token `-o'

Tags: macos, bash, git

I am getting error running a bash script to backup git branches:

The script is as follows:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash
# this shebang assumes you have bashv4 installed. If not, use /bin/bash

echo "running backup branch script"

current_branch="$(git branch | grep '\* ' | sed 's/^.*\( .*\)/\1/g')"

dltbranch() {
    git push origin --delete $1
    git push upstream --delete $1
    git branch -D $1
}

backup_branch() {
    git checkout $1
    git checkout -b backup__$1
    dltbranch $1
}

reset_branch() {
    the_new_current_branch="$(git branch | grep '\* ' | sed 's/^.*\( .*\)/\1/g')"
    echo "$the_new_current_branch"
    if [ ! $the_new_current_branch = $1 ]; then
        git checkout $1
    fi
}

branch_is_protected(){
    if [[ "$1" == dev* ]] -o [[ "$1" == "master"]] -o [[ "$1" == backup* ]]
    then
        echo "protected"
        exit 1
    else
        echo "not protected"
        exit 0
    fi
}

backup_all_branches(){
    branches="$(git for-each-ref refs/heads | cut -d/ -f3-)"
    echo $branches

    for branch in `echo "$branches"`; do

        backup_branch "$branch";
        # echo "$branch"
    done
}
```

As expected, I have no errors in shellcheck and can't see any errors. The issue is fixed by commenting out the `branch_is_protected`

```
branch_is_protected(){
    if [[ "$1" == dev* ]] -o [[ "$1" == "master"]] -o [[ "$1" == backup* ]]
    then
        echo "protected"
        exit 1
    else
        echo "not protected"
        exit 0
    fi
}
```

[image]

Any help appreciated, ty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `||` to represent either:

```
branch_is_protected(){
    if [[ "$1" == dev* || "$1" == "master" || "$1" == backup* ]]
    then
        echo "protected"
        exit 1
    else
        echo "not protected"
        exit 0
    fi
}
```

Comment: do you know why? everyone recommends the doubles

Comment: I changed to `if [ "$1" = dev* ] -o [ "$1" = "master"] -o [ "$1" = backup* ]` get `line 39: [: too many arguments`. line 39 is that line with all the [ ] tests

Comment: I confirm, it doesn't work either.

Comment: Actually tested — updated the answer

Comment: ooooooooo ok that makes sense

Comment: `-o` is the syntax for "or" used by the test command (i.e. within `[ ] expressions). Within `[[ ]]` or between commands, you need to use `||` instead. BTW the same applies to `-a` vs. `&&`.